# Can get the record set I want, Looking for advice

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Table layout

```
id, inactive (Boolean), name
12500, f, foo
12345, f, foo
12344, f, foo
12343, f, foo
12342, t, foo
12..., t, foo (more records)
12200, f, bar
12005, f, bar
12004, f, bar
12003, f, bar
12002, t, bar
12..., t, bar (more records)
..............(more records with different names)
```

Results:

- Need to group by name
- Need only inactive = f
- Need fist inactive = f, id
- Need a count of how many records, inactive = f, for each group

So from the example data above I would get the result set of:

```
id, inactive (Boolean), name, count
12343, f, foo, 157
12003, f, bar, 197
............. (any other names that fall into the above constraints)
```

Any help in the right direction would be great

Comment: first advice: write a sql statement.  then when it does not work, ask for help.

Comment: Thanks Randy for that advice, I did in fact write several queries and nothing worked as I wanted it to. Hence the question I asked. I thought it would be easier for someone to look at the needed results instead of my queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select min (id), inactive, name, count(*) from tabke where inactive = 'f' group by inactive, name
```

EDIT:

```
select b.minid, a.inactive, a.name, a.cnt from
(select inactive, name, count(*) cnt from table where inactive = 'f' group by inactive, name) a,
(select inactive, name, min(id) minid from table where inactive = 'f' group by inactive, name) b
where a.inactive = b.inactive and a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I needed to add more to the group by but your first solution works great